# How to transfer data from CForm View Class to CClass View class in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to create an application which reads the input from edit controls of the dialog box created with CForm View. I need to transfer this data to CView class(typically an array). What is the best way to achieve data transfer from one class to another in MFC?

Comment: *"What is the best way to achieve data transfer from one class to another in MFC?"* - It's the same as in any other C++ application. Nothing even remotely related to MFC. You need to learn C++ first (followed by the Windows API). See [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array from CYourFormView::m_arrDataOut, you can made a simply copy CYourView::m_arrDataIn by calling

```
m_arrDataIn.Copy(m_arrDataOut);
```

There is another way to transfer data, listed [here](http://www.codexpert.ro//forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=894).